# Power loss during 12v to 6/3 volt

Tags: dc, solar-cell

Does power loss happens while converting 12 volt DC to 6 volt or 3 volt with any method like using resistor, buck converter, divider
Which Wil give best efficiency running a dc light with 12 volt  or with 6 volt with same wattage of bulb..
I want to build a diy solar street light, available online kit are runs or 6 volt

Answer (score 3):

> Does power loss happens while converting 12 volt DC to 6 volt or 3 volt with any method like using ...

Yes.

> ... resistor,

Power will be wasted as heat. You can calculate this from \$ P = I^2 R \$ where \$P\$ will be the power in watts (W).

> ... buck converter,

A converter should have an efficiency rating. You can calculate the power loss using this figure.

> ... divider

See resistor above.

> Which Wil give best efficiency running a dc light with 12 volt or with 6 volt with same wattage of bulb.. I want to build a diy solar street light, available online kit are runs or 6 volt

If the lamp is 6 V then you have to use a 6 V supply. A buck convertor will be more efficient than a resistor and will run cooler.

All this, however, is the least of your problems. Presumably you don't need a street light when the sun is shining so you'll need battery storage. That means that you'll need a charge controller.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking DC step down regulators fall into 2 categories.

Some simply dissipate the extra voltage as heat. Examples of this are linear regulators, resistors, and diode voltage drops.

These all obey a simple efficiency equation. Efficiency = VOUT/VIN. If your VIN is 12V and your VOUT is 6V the efficiency is 50%, so half the power is wasted.

These types of regulators are cheap and simple, and they're a good solution when you only need a few mA of current.

Switching regulators are the other common type. These can theoretically reach 100% efficiency (in reality usually more like 80%). The can also step the voltage UP instead of down depending on the design. The downside is that they're more expensive and more complicated.

These are a good choice for devices that use a lot of power, a LED street light being a good example.